# If Godot scripts A and B both extend script C, do A and B share the same variable names of those from C?

Tags: godot

I'm new to the Godot engine.

If gd scripts A and B both extend script C and var_c is a variable in the script C, is var_c used in A different from var_c used in B?

So my scripts A and B extend script C.
A and B represent different states in a finite statement machine.
For example, in the finite state machine demo that came with the initial installment of Godot (from Steam), say C is motion.gd and A, B are move.gd and jump.gd.

I'm introducing a variable var_c in C hoping that it is "shared" by A and B in the sense that if var_c is updated in state A (say I write

```
var_c = 123
```

in script A) and when I enter state B, I wish to access the updated value of var_c like

```
if var_c == 123:
     print("A and B seem to share the same value of var_c!")
```

Unfortunately, it looks like var_c that I call in state A is independent of var_c called in state B. I might have made a mistake, but I want to know if it is true in general.

Are var_c used in A and var_c used in B the same? If they are different, how do I access one from the other? Like A.var_c and B.var_c?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scripts each have unique names (ex: examplescriptA.gd and examplescriptB.gd), the variables contained within should be local to that script, as Godot doesn't really recognize global variables in the strictest sense. 
If you want the equivalent of a global variable system (ie: a set of variables that can be accessed and updated from any other script), you should look into using `singletons`.

Documentation is here - https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html

I have also read about the notion of "extending" a script, and apparrently it is possible. It seems you can change the node inheritance in a script to extend another script (ex: `extends "res://your_script.gd"`). The only quirk, it seems, is you have to call `.ready()` in the `_ready()` function of the "parent" script. I have not had a chance to test this myself, however, and I'm not sure it works in both directions - for that, I would go the singleton route. Regardless, if you need a better reference the full discussion I took this from, you can find it here: https://godotengine.org/qa/2391/can-you-inherit-from-a-script

I hope you find least one of these helpful.